# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException in Sikuli

Tags: java

Doing the desktop automation with help of sikuli but when trying to call the image that time give the `"NullPointerException"` exception.

Code :

```
public static Screen s;
  public static void main(String arg[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException, Exception {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("images/Nintei_launch.exe");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        s.click("c:/Users/abc/Desktop/Winword/selectSession.PNG");
```

thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

you have an static object `Screen s`, this is declared but no initialized, 
so when you call `s.click()` you get a nullPointerException...

Take a look at this post:
[What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: plz check my code "public static Screen s;"

Comment: @IshwarDharmadhkari That is a declaration of a variable, not an initialization.

Comment: also initialized but same error

Comment: :) almost the same, if Screen is null you can do almost nothing with that object....